# How to get code coverage report from jest-junit in React project

Tags: react-native, jenkins, junit, jestjs

According to this [article](https://medium.com/@elisegev/running-tests-and-creating-code-coverage-reports-for-react-nodejs-project-continuously-with-60312b6a2dd0) I'd like to get jest-junit code coverage report (Option 2 in article)

So, in my package.json I invoke jest like this: `"test": "jest --config=jest.config.js",`

jest.config.js includes these settings:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: 'src/testCoverage',
  coverageReporters: [ "text"],
  reporters: ["default",
        ["jest-junit", {usePathForSuiteName: true, outputDirectory: 'src/testCoverage'}]
      ],
  testResultsProcessor: "jest-junit"
};
```

I did in this way because the written jest code in package.json doesn't work for me.

When I execute `npm run test` I get coverage data in src/testCoverage folder and junit.xml

Then I execute test stage in Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage('test') {
        steps{
        sh script:'''
          #!/bin/bash
          npm install -g yarn
          yarn install
          yarn add --dev jest-junit
          npm run test
        '''
        }
        post {
        always {
          junit 'src/testCoverage/junit.xml'
        }
      }
    }
```

But I don't see junit coverage report in Jenkins, while the article says that

> The line calling junit will publish the report that npm run test created

The only thing that I have - this is test result report of passed and failed tests.

Why I don't get junit coverage report in Jenkins? What should I do or change?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the junit.xml contains only the list of test cases executed and their duration.

In order to export the line coverage, you need some other coverage reported, for example, cobertura:

```
    coverageReporters: ['text', 'cobertura'],
```

It will produce coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml file containing the coverage information. Now you can use junit.xml to report the list of tests and cobertura-coverage.xml to report the line coverage to your CICD system.